# return statement in recursive javascript algoritum, how to return all the way up the stack?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Hey guys I am trying to write a pretty simple JSON delete function and I am recursively traversing the JSON. When I find a key value pair match I want to delete the pair in the JSON and return true for that the pair was found a deleted. The issue I am having is the return does not go all the way up the recursion stack. I realize I cannot just do this...

```
return true;
```

but I do not want to return the whole function. Do I need to do something like this?

```
return this.true;
```

I also want to break the recursion after a KV pair match is found instead of continuing the search the rest of the JSON. Currently it is continuing through the rest of the JSON. Is it possible to break the recursion after a match is found?

Here is some code, the hopefully makes it more clear.

```
deleteItems: function (toDelete) {
    self = this;
    var keys = toDelete.find(".key");
    var vals = toDelete.find(".val");

    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        $.each(this.json, function (key, val) {
            console.log(keys[i].value + " : " + vals[i].value);
        });
    }

    function remove(delKey, delVal, o) {
        console.log(delKey + " : " + delVal);
        for (var key in o) {
            if (typeof o[key] === "object") {
                console.log(key + " : [");
                remove(delKey, delVal, o[key]);
            } else {
                if (delKey == key && delVal == o[key]) {
                    console.log("delete match: " + delKey + " : " + delVal + " , " + key + " : " + o[key]);
                    //delete this item. 
                    return "true";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    console.log(remove(keys[0].value, vals[0].value, this.json));
},
```

Also if anyone else has an easier way to delete a KV pair from JSON using javascript I would love to hear it, there has to be an easier way then simply traversing the entire thing and delete the KV pair. And now actually looking at this I do not think it is going to work for nested object/ lists. for example if the KV pair is nested in the objects I do not think I can do delete json[key], I would need to keep track of the keys for the objects about it so it would need to be, delete json.obj1.obj2[key].

Thanks in advance for the help with the recursion and the tangent about deleting from JSON.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right, return does *not* go all the way up the stack, it goes level by level.

Let's see what you can do to deal with it!

You are returning from here:

```
  if (delKey == key && delVal == o[key]) {
       console.log("delete match: " + delKey + " : " + delVal + " , " + key + " : " + o[key]);
       //delete this item. 
       return true;
   }
```

The problem is, that doesn't matter for the rest of the methods calling the algorithm, what we'd like done 
is for them to stop when a match is found.

You have this line:

```
remove(delKey, delVal, o[key]);
```

We'd like some indication of what happened there, something like this could work:

```
if(remove(delKey, delVal, o[key])){ // if I got a match, return true;
    return true;
}
```

This way, success would bubble up across all the call stack. We're checking if the result of the smaller problem solved our bigger problem (in this case, meaning it returned true). If it does, our problem is solved and we ourselves return true.

There are other ways to solve this, but this way is good because it solves the *recursive problem* at hand. We solved the smaller issue which leads to solving the bigger one.

There are other approaches, for example, you could throw an exception and catch it at the highest level, negating the need for changing the code (changing `return true` to `throw true` and catching that on the highest level. They work, but they're conceptually wrong, since they make less recursive sense.

Another protip, return `true` (which is a language value for truthfulness) and not `"true"` which is just a string.

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
            remove(delKey, delVal, o[key]);
```

to:

```
            if (remove(delKey, delVal, o[key]) == "true") {
                return "true";
            }
```

Comment: You got an up-vote from me. Your solution seems correct, (and only 10 seconds after mine which rules out anything suspicious anyway) even if it lacks explanation. I don't know why anyone would down-vote it.

Comment: All I can think of is that before I edited it, I had `return true` instead of `return "true"`. As far the lack of explanation, I felt that it's simple enough that it doesn't really need it.

Comment: @Barmar I've upvoted as well. However, you can use `return true;` instead of `return "true";`, right? Not sure why you would want to return the string 'true' instead of the boolean.

Comment: I was making the minimum number of changes to his code to make it work, so I didn't change the other place where he was already returning a string.